# Is it possible to hide dates from previous/next months in Antd DatePicker/RangePicker?

Tags: datetime, datepicker, hide, antd

Ref: [Antd DatePicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/)

I'm using the Ant Design RangePicker specifically and would like to only show dates from the current month (eg. under Feb, 1 - 28, and under Mar, 1 - 31).

The default displays some of the previous month's dates, as well as some of the next month's dates.

Is this possible?

[image: Antd RangePicker, comparing default to the desired result.]

Comment: is it possible for you to use `CSS`?

Comment: It's technically possible for me to add style rules, however, I'm not sure how I would target "non-current month dates".

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wopkwn?file=index.css is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! Amazing, thanks so much @SaeedShamloo 

Comment: You're welcome, is it ok to post it as answer?

Comment: Absolutely, go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using some `CSS` styles, like this:

```
.ant-picker-date-panel .ant-picker-cell:not(.ant-picker-cell-in-view) .ant-picker-cell-inner {
  display: none;
}

.ant-picker-date-panel .ant-picker-cell:not(.ant-picker-cell-in-view) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I've implemented an example [Here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wopkwn?file=index.js), you can check it out and find the example source code.